# Get resource ID (R.string.name) of string value from Android attr in custom view

Tags: android, kotlin, attr, declare-styleable

My application has a custom view, styled by `attrs.xml` entry:

```xml
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyView">
        <attr name="title" format="reference" />
        <attr name="image" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In my custom view, I need to retreive the resource ID of resource specified as `title` in `attrs.xml`, but I can only retreive the content of string specified as `title`. Fo far, I've tried using:

```kotlin
attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(R.styleable.MyView_title, 0)
```

And

```kotlin
getSourceResourceId(R.styleable.MyView_title, 0)
```

But in both cases, the returned value is the default `0`.

I've tries the same approach with other types of attributes, and for example, Drawable ID can be easilly retrieved by:

```kotlin
getResourceId(R.styleable.MyView_image, 0)
```

Is there any way to check what R.string was provided in XML?

Comment: getResourceId(R.styleable.MyView_title, 0) doesn't work?

Comment: No, it only returns `0`, the specified default value

Comment: can you add the xml for the layout?

Comment: it seems as though you are setting the title value with a string, rather than a reference..